# Parts of the FBX getting flipped upon import from Blender to Unity

Tags: unity, blender

I am trying to import a race track into unity, which I have modeled in blender. The problem is some objects of the model are getting flipped, to be specific all the curbs on the sides of the race track are getting rotated except one. I have already applied transforms and the direction in Y up on export. Below are the images of what is happening exactly.[image: This is in blender]

[image: This is what happens to the curbs and the one that doesn't get flipped]

[A link to the FBX file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15wtS26B7Q-jLFofkX6lWBgm6eFw0fTW6/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

In Unity you can select all the curbs that are inverted, change scale Y value to -1, and then simply drag them down/up to the right height.

Comment: You are right but there has to be a reason why its not getting imported properly.